# Windows SBS Server 2011 High Memory Useage

Tags: memory, iis, windows-server

Have a Windows SBS Server I've encountered which I have suspicions it's been compromised in some way.

Symptoms:

11.8gb of 12gb total RAM at all times, even after restricting the Exchange store to 4gb.

Multiple instances of w3wp.exe which I understand are IIS databases running. 9 in total using over 1gb of RAM.

Multiple login failures appearing in Event log.

Windows Update turned off, not through obvious GPEdit policies. 45 outstanding Windows Critical updates.

Disabled firewalls (inbuilt and Kaspersky). Hardware firewall (on router) is running and configured for incoming RDP, FTP, SMTP directed to Server.

Ongoing slowness of the network regardless of any 'upgrades' (gigabit cards fitted to all Workstations).

What should be my next steps? How can I track where and what IIS databases have been setup/run. How about SQL server, would you expect that to be running with Exchange and FTP? Any tools I can run to check what has been opened on the server?

Comment: My next step (in the morning) with the Hardware and OS support company is to close it up, install all the security updates etc. Is Malwarebytes capable of closing IIS databases etc on SBS2011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if anything is actually wrong. Our own SBS is currently sitting at 11.6GB.
[image]

The SBS contains a lot of services that eat a lot of RAM. For an Exchange server alone, I would usually commission [12GB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346700.aspx?ppud=4) alone.

You might want to check if you're running SharePoint and shut that down if you don't need it. Usually, I'd get [another 12GB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) for that.

So, I'm not surprised. If this isn't normal, then I'd have a problem as well ;)

Comment: Are you running IIS? 8 different instances of w3wp.exe which from what i've read so far are different databases, your usage seems similar to what we have. I'm confident we're not running Sharepoint. Exchange is restricted, yet only has to service 3 mailboxes, 2 of them very light usage. I'm pondering restricting the store further...

Comment: After getting two seperate support engineers to investigate they're 100% sure it's not been exploited and it's just attempts as the firewalls not locked down enough... Will be configuring it and tightening things to shore it up. Thanks for reassuring me!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot replying to your first comment. Yes, we run IIS, we need it to supply OWA and SharePoint. Please keep in mind that the minimal memory amount for SBS2011 is [already 8GB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491249.aspx). So this isn't even too far off that value.

Comment: Agreed, 12GB isn't much for SBS2011, but when it's only serving 3 PC's/users (2 of which are very light usage) i'm rather annoyed it's so sluggish... Then also not surprised when running some large database software alongside Exchange.